# $k$-dimensional normal distribution function

Tags: integration, functions, normal-distribution

If $f(\vec{x})$ is a vector of normal distribution function and assuming that $\sigma$ is same in all dimension, can we say that

$$ f(\vec{x}) = \prod_{1\leq i \leq k} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma^2}}

\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\exp\big(-{(x_{i}-\mu_{x,i})^2}/{2\sigma^2}\big) \mathrm{d}x_{i}\ $$

Comment: I can't see the difference between this and [your previous question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/58833)...

Comment: @J.M.: in the previous question the OP didn't give a formula that is nonsensical in view of the question. Best I can tell $f(x)$ defined in the question is independent of $x$.

Comment: Yes, I did not mention the formula in my last question. that is why I repeat the question to make it more clear

Comment: @shaik: please, next time edit the question with the new information, so as to minimize duplication.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you mean "$\sigma$ is the same in all *directions*" -- a spherically symmetric distribution. That would force the above density, and independence of the coordinates $x_i$.

If you mean the joint normal distribution of several coordinate "dimensions" $X_i$, where each dimension considered by itself is normal with the same $\sigma$, then the formula holds if and only if all these dimensions are statistically independent of each other (no correlation between different coordinates).

Edit: ... that is all true *if* you remove the integral signs from the formula.  For the formula as it was posted, $f(x)$ is independent of $x$ because of the integration.

Comment: Yes, I am assuming that all the dimensions are independent of each other.

Comment: *...then the formula holds...* Seriously?

Comment: Yes. $ $ $ $ $ $

Answer (score 4):

The formula as written is absurd: the integral makes the rhs equal to one... Without the integral sign, this is a special case of the multivariate normal density.